# BottomNavigationView with drawermenu and fab

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, floating-action-button

The designer at my company wants me to make something like this for a BottomNavigationBar:

[image: Screenshot]

that is, a BottomNavigationView with a drawermenu on the left and an overlapping fab on the right. As far as I can tell, this is not covered in any of the documentation or guidelines, perhaps also not recommended at all.

But still, my question is, how can I do it? Is the BottomNavigationView the right thing to start with or is there other components more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

try use BottomaAppBar component, 
[Material design BottomAppBar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/)

It's mixed Fab and Toolbar. Using `app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"`in Fab, You create some visual connection and using `app:fabAlignmentMode="center"` on Your BottomAppBar You can set Fab position.